# How to Show/ hide part of canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is My [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufrnn2jw/)

I have a requirement like when user clicks on center circle, that should toggle outer circle and when user clicks on outer small circles that should change center circle value.

Here i am not getting how to Show/ hide part of Canvas when user clicks on center circle?

Any help on how to do this?

```js
GenerateCanvas();

function GenerateCanvas() {
    try {
        var FlagCircleCenterCoordinates = new Array();
        var FlagCircles = [];
        
        var CenterX = document.getElementById('canvasFlag').width / 2;
        var CenterY = document.getElementById('canvasFlag').height / 2;

        var OuterTrackRadius = 98;
        var InnerTrackRadius = 70;
        var InnerCircleRadius = 20;

        var FlagElement = document.getElementById("canvasFlag");
        var ObjContext = FlagElement.getContext("2d");

        // Outer track
        ObjContext.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        ObjContext.beginPath();
        ObjContext.arc(CenterX, CenterY, OuterTrackRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ObjContext.strokeStyle = '#CCC';
        ObjContext.stroke();
        ObjContext.fill();

        // Inner track
        ObjContext.beginPath();
        ObjContext.arc(CenterX, CenterY, InnerTrackRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ObjContext.strokeStyle = '#CCC';
        ObjContext.stroke();

        // Inner small circle
        ObjContext.beginPath();
        ObjContext.arc(CenterX, CenterY, InnerCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ObjContext.strokeStyle = '#CCC';
        ObjContext.stroke();
        
        //Max 17...other wide need to change the Inner and Outer circle radius
        var FlagImagesArray =  [1, 2, 3,4,5];

        if (FlagImagesArray.length > 0) {
            var StepAngle = 2 * Math.PI / FlagImagesArray.length;
            var FlagCircleRadius = (OuterTrackRadius - InnerTrackRadius) / 2;
            var RadiusOfFlagCircleCenters = OuterTrackRadius - FlagCircleRadius;

            for (var LoopCnt in FlagImagesArray) {
                var CircleCenterCoordinates = new Object();
                
                 CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionX = CenterX + (Math.cos(StepAngle * (parseInt(LoopCnt) + 1)) * RadiusOfFlagCircleCenters);
                 CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionY = CenterY + (Math.sin(StepAngle * (parseInt(LoopCnt) + 1)) * RadiusOfFlagCircleCenters);
                
                ObjContext.beginPath();
                ObjContext.arc(CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionX, CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionY, FlagCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ObjContext.strokeStyle = '#CCC';
                ObjContext.stroke();
                ObjContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
                ObjContext.fillText(FlagImagesArray[LoopCnt], CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionX, CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionY); 
                
                FlagCircleCenterCoordinates[LoopCnt] = CircleCenterCoordinates;
                
                var ObjFlagCircle = {
                    Left : CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionX - FlagCircleRadius,
                    Top : CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionY - FlagCircleRadius,
                    Right : CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionX + FlagCircleRadius,
                    Bottom : CircleCenterCoordinates.PostionY + FlagCircleRadius,
                    FlagName : FlagImagesArray[LoopCnt]
                }
                
                FlagCircles[LoopCnt] = ObjFlagCircle;
            }
                        
            $('#canvasFlag').mousemove(function (Event) {
                 debugger;
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');

                var ClickedX = Event.pageX - $('#canvasFlag').offset().left;
                var ClickedY = Event.pageY - $('#canvasFlag').offset().top;
                for (var Count = 0; Count < FlagCircles.length; Count++) {
   
                    if (ClickedX < FlagCircles[Count].Right &&
                        ClickedX > FlagCircles[Count].Left &&
                        ClickedY > FlagCircles[Count].Top &&
                        ClickedY < FlagCircles[Count].Bottom) {
                        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            
            $('#canvasFlag').click(function (Event) {
                 debugger;
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');

                var ClickedX = Event.pageX - $('#canvasFlag').offset().left;
                var ClickedY = Event.pageY - $('#canvasFlag').offset().top;
                for (var Count = 0; Count < FlagCircles.length; Count++) {
   
                    if (ClickedX < FlagCircles[Count].Right &&
                        ClickedX > FlagCircles[Count].Left &&
                        ClickedY > FlagCircles[Count].Top &&
                        ClickedY < FlagCircles[Count].Bottom) {
                            ObjContext.fillStyle = "#FFF";
                            ObjContext.beginPath();
                            ObjContext.arc(CenterX, CenterY, InnerCircleRadius - 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                            ObjContext.closePath();                        
                            ObjContext.fill();
                        
                            ObjContext.fillStyle = "blue";
                            ObjContext.fillText(FlagCircles[Count].FlagName, CenterX, CenterY); 
                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (E) {
        alert(E);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasFlag" width="200" height="200">
    Your browser does not support the canvas
</canvas>
```

Comment: Voting to close this question: The element chosen by the questioner (html5 canvas) is not suitable for their exact requirements.  The questioner wants to show/hide individual elements on the canvas without clearing the canvas. Drawings on html5 canvas cannot be shown & hidden individually because the canvas retains no reference to any individual drawing that it has already done onto its surface.

Comment: @markE there is a property called clip-path in css which will show a particular part of element (canvas in my case) which suits exactly to my requirements.
But the problem is it will not support in all the browsers.
I am trying to find the solution which can be done in the same way

Comment: The canvas has a similar clipping ability, but if you don't want to erase & redraw the canvas content, then this canvas clipping ability can't be used as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man. Ok so first off, you'll need to get rid of the try/catch statement, it isn't doing anything.

Next you'll need to make all those vars you have outside of the function body, we need to be able to access them from another function

It looks like you have all your click functionality done, and it's working too. That's good, just go ahead and move both of the lines that start with jquery outside of the generateCanvas function. They only need to run once, and we're going to need to call generate canvas again.

Fourth, make a variable to toggle the outer circle off and on somewhere, and only draw the outer ring in generateCanvas() when that variable is true. You should also set another Global variable that gets set to Count, right before you break, so that you can remember it when you regenerate the canvas.
Take all the code you have in your click function to draw the inner circle with the number, and put that inside of generate canvas. Make sure that code only calls if the variable you used to remember Count is set to something (ie you had already clicked an outer number)

Next, add a generateCanvas() call in your click function.Now your click function sets the variable you use to represent the center value, redraws the canvas, and returns. You'll need more logic in your mouse down function in order to figure out when you clicked the center, but based on the code you already have you can figure that out, your main problem is just that this was set up to run once, not multiple times. That makes the canvas a lot more like an image instead of an active drawing element

Don't forget to add FlagElement.width = FlagElement.width to clear the canvas! (or just draw a background over it)

Comment: hey @Jack I don't want to do any thing on catch block. It's just for dev purpose and it's not class file that if some exception occurred and i need to do some thing based on exception

Comment: When i am able to do every thing in one function why should i split and increase my JS size?

Comment: As my requirement is i need to show hide not redrawing the canvas

Comment: and one more thing if you have ans do in JS fiddle and share here, not by redrawing i need this by Show/ hide manner like image sprite

Comment: Because you need to. I know for a fact that that mouse down call is stacking on iteself. It shouldn't be called. Your variables NEED to be global, or outside of that function. I'm not suggesting you use anything other than generateCanvas, just pull the two event listeners out of it, that won't even affect js size

Comment: As it's not causing any issue i don't want to split

Comment: There is no Hide Show, that's the only way that canvas works. Trust me, I redraw the canvas 60 frames a second without lag using Huge resources and tons of effects and stuff. It's not going to suffer, it's made to do this.

Comment: It's same as my JS fiddle

Comment: Ok well go ahead and put the generateCanvas call in the mousedown function, you'll need to rerun that function when you click, there is NO avoiding that

Comment: answer is this from you "need to redraw".

and i don't want do that.As a dev i know that min thing and coding standards.
That's why i mentioned the title of question as Show/Hide

Comment: Ok Assuming you want to Show and hide, which canvases dont do, you would want to make 2 canvases, draw the inner circle to one, draw the outer circle to the second, duplicate all your functions and then figure out the HTML to make them both overlay, and you'll be suffering a harder performance hit when putting the two layers over each other when Css has to rerender and do exactly the same thing. So go ahead man. You get it.

Comment: I don't want to do with multiple canvas elements.
I need the same with single.This is the thing which can be done using clip-path property of CSS.

But it has some browser compatbility issues
Solution should be centralized, not to change the structure

Comment: Ok then you you need 1 canvas, you draw the inside to it, you save it as an image, you use the same canvas and draw the outside to it, you save that as an image, and with 2 images you'll be able to go right back to HTML or wherever you came from. Var img = new Image(); img.src = $('#canvas').toDataURL(); Now img can be appended to the DOM with $('#el').append(img) and be given a css class like img.className = "cssClass1"

Comment: Outer circles are depends on User input.
If i keeps on saving the images for every input of user then it will create a lot of just files.
For removing those i will need to do manually or run a service

Comment: You want to rerender the canvas. Canvas is made for exactly what you're doing. I'm telling you how to do it. But you're scared and that's ok. A rerender is as fast as it gets. You could easily hit 100 renders every second on a phone with an image as simple as this.